# What is the best way to convert a long datetime into an actual datetime in a SQL Server database?

Tags: sql-server, performance, query-optimization

In my Microsoft SQL Server database, every date or datetime is represented as a `decimal(17,0)` value.

For example: 20210722054500000 would translate to 2021-07-22 05:45:00:000

I already came up with an solution to convert this:

```
SELECT 
    CONVERT(datetime, (SUBSTRING(CAST(20210722054500000 AS varchar(20)), 1, 4) + '-' + 
                       SUBSTRING(CAST(20210722054500000 AS varchar(20)), 5, 2) + '-' + 
                       SUBSTRING(CAST(20210722054500000 AS varchar(20)), 7, 2) + ' ' + 
                       SUBSTRING(CAST(20210722054500000 AS varchar(20)), 9, 2) + ':' + 
                       SUBSTRING(CAST(20210722054500000 AS varchar(20)), 11, 2) + ':00'), 120)
```

It works, but I feel there should be an better solution to convert this.

So my question is has anybody an approach that requires less code or would be better in regards to performance?

Comment: Fixing the design long term, and correcting all the columns, is the real answer.

Comment: Judicious use of `/` and `%` can be used to extract the elements whilst staying in the realm of numbers, rather than going "stringly typed" and then `DATETIME2FROMPARTS` is probably your friend.

Comment: What does "better" mean?

Comment: Thanks for asking. With better I mean leass code or better performance. I updated the question.

Comment: @Larnu : Since this is the database of an old ERP system correcting the columns is not an suitable option. But indeed if I had the chance I would totally follow you.

Comment: Better performance = storing the data correctly (maybe in an _additional_ table in/from your ERP). Less code = code golf, generally. You can make something really terse without that being _better_ except in terms of character count, which is far less valuable to most than clarity.

Comment: To add to @AaronBertrand's comment, you can also make code that is very short, however, far from performant. For example, a `WHILE` can be a very short way to write the logic to do something (say, split a delimited string into rows), however, it'll be far less performant than say a solution set based solution or creating a CLR function. Shorter != faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it without casts and string functions, using datetimefromparts:

```
declare @input decimal(17,0) = 20210722054500000
select DATETIMEFROMPARTS(
    @input/10000000000000      ,-- year
    @input/100000000000 % 100  ,-- month
    @input/1000000000 % 100    ,-- day
    @input/10000000 % 100      ,-- hour
    @input/100000%100          ,-- minute
    @input/1000%100            ,-- seconds
    @input%1000                -- milliseconds 
)
```

Answer (score 2):

One way is to extract the parts using a simple set of substrings. Given this table and data:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.WhoDesignedThis
(
  Id int,
  TheDate decimal(17,0) -- this was hard to write with a straight face
);

INSERT dbo.WhoDesignedThis(Id, TheDate) VALUES
(1, 20210722054500000),
(2, 19991231132247699);
```

This query:

```
;WITH x AS
(
  SELECT Id, TheDate, x = CONVERT(char(17), TheDate) 
  FROM dbo.WhoDesignedThis
)
SELECT Id, TheDate, output = DATETIMEFROMPARTS
  (
    LEFT(x,4), 
    SUBSTRING(x,5,2), 
    SUBSTRING(x,7,2), 
    SUBSTRING(x,9,2), 
    SUBSTRING(x,11,2), 
    SUBSTRING(x,13,2), 
    RIGHT(x,3)
  )
FROM x;
```

Produces these results:

| Id | TheDate | output |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 20210722054500000 | 2021-07-22 05:45:00.000 |
| 2 | 19991231132247699 | 1999-12-31 13:22:47.700 |

- Example [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=84770cc8bc6244951d7544e7599d2f72)